# Member function overload based on namespaced typedefed primitif types

Tags: c++, namespaces, overloading, typedef

The following code fails to compile with g++ 4.8, in both C++03 and C++11

```
namespace N {typedef int A;}
namespace NN {typedef int A;}

struct Z
{
    void foo(N::A){}
    void foo(NN::A){}
};
```

The error is

```
d.cpp:7:10: erreur: ‘void Z::foo(NN::A)’ cannot be overloaded
     void foo(NN::A){}};
          ^
d.cpp:6:6: erreur: with ‘void Z::foo(N::A)’
 void foo(N::A){}
```

I have always thought that types in different namespaces were different types, no matter what.
But it seems not. I feel like at the end the compiler gets rid off the namespace/typedef and focus on the underlying type and it clashes.

Am I right ? Do you have a workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

Types don't live in namespaces. *Names* do. You overload on types, not on names.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but types do have a name, thus also lives in a namespace, aren't they ?

Comment: @Davidbrcz: You're wrong. Types can have more than one name; that's what typedef does.

Comment: @rici: Types can also have *no* name, e.g. the types of lambda expressions. You can *give* them a name (`decltype`, or by binding to a template parameter), but you don't have to.

Comment: @KerrekSB: indeed. The constraint is that once a name is bound to a type, it must remain bound to the same type for the rest of the program ("diagnostic not required").

Answer (score 1):

A `typedef` is just another name for the same type. You can only overload on different types.